# <ul> floating right, but no float:right;s have been defined

Tags: html, css

I am designing a webstore for a wine selling business, and I am trying to make a list of all of the wineries we get wine from 3 items wide, and centered on the page.

What is happening is that the li are somehow being aligned, floated, positioned, moved or something else to the right side of the ul, even though I have not defined any 'right-{anything}'s.
Nor are my red borders working, but that's a problem for later.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="overall">
<div class="maincontent">
<h1>Wineries</h1>
    <div id="winerytable">
    <p><img alt="Red box around cell" src="images/wineries/redboxsml.png" /> - These Wineries only sell to their Wine List. You need to obtain a spot on their lists to receive their wine.</p>
        <ul class="winerieslist">
            <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/collections/Adamant-Cellars"><img alt="Adamant Cellars Image" src="images/wineries/Adamant Cellars.png" height="300px" /><br />Adamant Cellars</a></li>
            <li class="redborderlistitem"><a href="https://mywebsite.com/collections/aMaurice-Cellars"><img alt="aMaurice Cellars Image" src="images/wineries/aMaurice Cellars.png" height="300px" /><br />aMaurice Cellars</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/collections/Amavi-Cellars"><img alt="Amavi Cellars Image" src="images/wineries/Amavi Cellars.png" height="300px" /><br />Amavi Cellars</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/collections/Adamant-Cellars"><img alt="Adamant Cellars Image" src="images/wineries/Adamant Cellars.png" height="300px" /><br />Adamant Cellars</a></li>
            <li class="redborderlistitem"><a href="https://mywebsite.com/collections/aMaurice-Cellars"><img alt="aMaurice Cellars Image" src="images/wineries/aMaurice Cellars.png" height="300px" /><br />aMaurice Cellars</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://mywebsite.com/collections/Amavi-Cellars"><img alt="Amavi Cellars Image" src="images/wineries/Amavi Cellars.png" height="300px" /><br />Amavi Cellars</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
#overall {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.maincontent {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.maincontent a:link, a:visited {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.maincontent a:hover, a:active {
    color: #609;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.maincontent ul {
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.maincontent li {
    padding-top: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

#winerytable {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.winerieslist {
}

.winerieslist ul {
    float: left;
}

.winerieslist li {
    background-image: url('images/wineries/listitembg.png');
    width: 310px;
}

.redborderlistitem {
    border: 5px;
    border-color: #F00;
}
```

I apologize if I am just missing something really simple, but I have been tearing my hair out trying to get the list centered. Thanks in advance for any answers you give!

Oh, and before you comment on it: yes, I realize some css isn't used or completed. There are other pages this css uses and this page isn't finished yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be default the element ul has padding.

Add this line `ul { padding:0px }`

And you will see the change.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/LZrLG/)